# If we format and re-install OSX through recovery, will it install the latest version?

Tags: macos, mac

If we format and re-install OSX through Recovery Mode, will it download and install the latest version of OSX or use the existing version? I'm asking this because I noticed that it is downloading some files during the re-installation.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following links:

[About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

[How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

From the latter link:

> ### Start up from macOS Recovery
>
> [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314) installs
>   different versions of macOS depending on the key combination you press
>   while starting up. Hold down one of these combinations immediately
>   after pressing the power button to turn on your Mac. Release when you
>   see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
>
> - Command-R - Reinstall the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac, without upgrading to a later version.<sup>1</sup>
> - Option-Command-R - Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac.<sup>2</sup>
> - Shift-Option-Command-R - Reinstall the macOS that came with your Mac, or the version closest to it that is still available.
>     Requires [macOS Sierra 10.12.4](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201260) or later.
>
>   1. If you're selling or giving away a Mac that is using OS X El Capitan or earlier, use Option-Command-R to make sure that the
>        installation isn't associated with your Apple ID.
>   2. If you haven't already installed macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later, Option-Command-R reinstalls the macOS that came with your Mac, or the
>        version closest to it that is still available.

Answer (score -2):

in my experience using internet recovery

it install the original bundled version macosx from the internet